# Writing a measurement to a file using python

Tags: raspbian, python, ds18b20

I'm new to Raspberry so I need a bit of help. 
I have a DS18B20 temperature sensor, which I want to write the measurements into a file. 
I have a script running, making measurement printing to screen every second, at the same time it updates the text file with the last measurement, but I would like to have all the measurements in the text file.

I'm using this script:

```
print(read_temp())

dataAsInt = (read_temp())

    dataAsString = str(dataAsInt)

    fb = open("/home/pi/test2","a" '\n')
    fb.write(dataAsString) 
    fb.close()
```

I've tryed using "a" for appending instead of writing and '\n' for writing on next line.

Hope someone can point me the right direction.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please note that the question is not Pi specific (and therefore off-topic) but only related to python as a general programming language.

Comment: Thanks, so I should have posted in what group instead?

Comment: Technically that would be Stack Overflow. But lets try to sort this one out here. If it's closed afterwards, well than that's that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fb = open('/home/pi/test2','a+')`

should do the trick. It opens the file in appending mode for read and write access. Placing the `'\n'` there is not what you want. Instead simply explicitly append a '\n' each time you want a line break, e.g. `fb.write('\n')`. For the given example that would look like:

```
dataAsInt = (read_temp())
dataAsString = str(dataAsInt)

fb = open('/home/pi/test2','a+')
fb.write(dataAsString) 
fb.write('\n')
fb.close()
```

Note that [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) states (i.e. there will be a line break, maybe your text editor just does not treat it right):

> The default is to use text mode, which may convert '\n' characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading.

Comment: Adding the 'a+' fixed the problem with adding all measurements. 
But I can't get the \n to work.

Comment: If you put `fb.write('\n')` after `fb.write(dataAsString)` (on the next line) that does not add a line break? It should.

Comment: I misunderstood you the first time.
It fixes the problem, i'm now logging my temperature in the text file with new line for every measurement. Thanks a lot